# How to boot to usb from Grub2, when the BIOS keep booting solely to Grub despite what boot order

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hp, bios

I'm having a constant battle with Bios boot options and grub...
for example, I have windows 7 on a USB that i wish to install on my laptop (which has 2 HDDs, both have a Linux distro on them (ubuntu and arch), i select it on the USB on the HP Bios, which it still boots to Grub anyways... how does it do it is there any way on booting from grub to usb to install over the Arch Linux?

I made the USB using Rufus.

Thanks,

Comment: Your USB flash has not been created properly, and is not bootable. Probably because with was created with/without UEFI support. Retry to create it, choosing different options in Rufus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

There are different keys for entering into the boot menu for various models you can fid them [here](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779#here).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Locate where the vmlinuz or vmlinuz-linux and initrd.gz or initramfs-linux.img files are located.

Insert the USB drive.

Boot the system.

Press `C` to get to the command-line.

Find the partitions:

```
grub> ls
```

This will show you the available devices.

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd1) (hd1,msdos0)
```

Use this information, along with our knowledge of where the vmlinuz or vmlinuz-linux and initrd.gz or initramfs-linux.img files are to boot the system, suppose USB drive is hd1,msdos1 /dev/sdb1, run this:

```
grub> linux (hd1,msdos1)/install/vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1
grub> initrd (hd1,msdos1)/install/initrd.gz
grub> boot
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to boot Windows 10 from USB using grub:

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) ...
grub> set root=hd0,msdos1 
grub> chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
grub> boot
```

where `(hd0,msdos1)` is the bootable Windows USB Stick.

Comment: For an ubuntu 22.04 usb, bootx64.efi failed but replacing with grubx64.efi succeeded.